# Entity Framework how to disable Windows Authentication for transferable database file

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the Entity Framework Model First database which is based on .mdf file.

When I'm creating a DB file via the EF Visual Studio tool, I can use this DB file only on this computer (because of Windows Authentication).

So, I couldn't insert completed DB file (.mdf) in deployment package such as Install Shield Wizard, because all users, who will use it, will have troubles when my program program tries connecting to the DB file (the reason is the same - because of Windows Authentication).

So, is there the way to insert DB file in deployment package? [The creation of the db file (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9q0R.png)